# Osascript to Bash Command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, applescript, alfred

This is very simple. Just can't get it right.

I am making a alfredworkflow, where I want to take a URL, then curl / wget (program doesnt matter) in terminal. If I can do this in the background that would be excellent, but if it needs to open terminal I can live with that.

So far what I have:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
  set theURL to URL of active tab of window 1
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "echo "${theURL}
end tell
```

Comment: Isn't this AppleScript, not ActionScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set theURL to URL of active tab of window 1
end tell
do shell script "curl --remote-name '" & theURL & "'"
```

The string concatenation operator in AppleScript is `&`, and you don't put `${...}` around variables.

This will run `curl` in the background, there's no need to open a terminal. The `--remote-name` option tells it to write the result to a file named like the filename part of the URL.